# Accessing javascript variable in php and prevent body to load before some event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating one application where the location of the user will be fetched, and it will be shows in the  map. Also, The city of the user I am fetching. I have created one separate master.js where I have putted all the fetching code. Now I have put function in window.onload which will call the function of map where latitude and longitude will be fetched and one function will be called from there which is to fetch the city of the user.

```
function showcityname(userLatlng){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      "location": userLatlng
    },
    function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        var city_name = results[0].address_components[4].long_name;//to get address
        //window.location="?city_name="+ city_name;

        alert(city_name);
         document.cookie = "name=" + city_name ;        
        //fetchcity(city_name);
        // window.location = "?city=" + city_name;      

     // else
      //  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Unable to retrieve your address" + "<br />";
   });
}
```

Now I want to make application like using this city_name the query will be fired to database, and it will be shown on the page the relative data from the database. The problem is the body loaded before it fetches the city. So the relevant data is not shown to page. I want to make that the city_name variable first should be assign to variable and then the body should execute so I can show relative data. I have user document.cookie but it did not work if user first time comes to my website, It will worked only if the user refresh the page. May be its problem of window.onload.. How to stop the body to load before the city name comes.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you get parameter `userLatlng`?

Comment: using positio.coords.latitude and longitude I will get the usetLatLng. The problem is I have set it onload, So it will execute after the body will be loaded. I want to make it like after fetching of city_name the body should be loaded

Comment: I don't know what is your other code. Do you use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` to get `userLatlng`? If that is the case and you are not using some markers to get position than you can retrieve all your data from DB and load map after that.

Comment: Ya I am using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` to get current position of the user. Body load before it gets the location of the user. I want to make like after fetching the city of the user the body should be executed.

Comment: `getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous and needs some time to get results. Also your call to DB needs some time. I don't know what is the best way to manage it. One option is to display limited information to user until you get customer location and check of it and after that show the map with all relevant information.